# Four 1byte char to One 4byte int?

Tags: c++, c, char, int, type-conversion

I have an char array of 1000 bytes. I want to convert it into int array such that four elements of char array (each of one byte) is equal to one element of int array (each of four bytes).

```
e.g.:
char_array[0] = '0'
char_array[1] = '9'
char_array[2] = '2'
char_array[3] = '8'

it should be converted to
int_array[0] = 928 or 0928.
```

How should I do that?

Comment: Do you want to convert characters to numbers or bytes to ints? Your sample code hints to the former, your first paragraph to the latter. Maybe you just need `atoi`?

Comment: Many answers possibles. Could you put more specific code ?

Comment: `n = 1000*0 + 100*9 + 2*10 + 1*8`: show what you have tried.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

#define CHAR_ARRAY_SIZE 8

int main()
{
    char charArray[CHAR_ARRAY_SIZE] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'};

    int intArray[2];
    for(int i = 0; i < CHAR_ARRAY_SIZE/4; i++) {
        char ch1 = (charArray[4*i+0] - '0');
        char ch2 = (charArray[4*i+1] - '0');
        char ch3 = (charArray[4*i+2] - '0');
        char ch4 = (charArray[4*i+3] - '0');

        intArray[i] = ch1*1000 + ch2*100 + ch3*10 + ch4;
    }
    cout << "intArray[0] : " << intArray[0] << endl;
    cout << "intArray[1] : " << intArray[1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For each character in the array, add the digit to the value we're building. (We multiply by 10 beforehand to adjust the digits).

Every 4 digits, add to the integer array and reset the value.

```
int value = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
   value *= 10;
   value += char_array[i] - '0'
   if(i % 4 == 3){
      int_array[i/4] = value;
      value = 0;
   }
}
```

Note that this will not work if char_array contains chars other than the digits 0-9, but that's any easy check to add.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `sscanf` to convert your array to an int value. If you want to have 4 bytes of the `char` array to be converted into one `int` then simply split the array into 4 byte chunks and scan them one by one, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char char_array[8] = {'0', '9', '2', '8', '1', '2', '3', '4'};
    int array_size = sizeof(char_array) / sizeof(char_array[0]);

    int sizeof_int = sizeof(int);
    int int_array[array_size / sizeof_int];

    char buf[sizeof_int + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i += sizeof_int)
    {
        memcpy(buf, char_array + i, sizeof_int);
        buf[sizeof_int] = '\0';
        int val = 0;
        if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &val) == -1)
          return -1; // return in case scanf returns an error
        int_array[i / sizeof_int] = val;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array_size / sizeof_int; i++)
      printf("%d\n", int_array[i]);
}
```

This will produce

```
928
1234
```

as an output.

---

Oh by the way, since you're using C-Style arrays I assume you also want a C solution. Otherwise I'd suggest to use `vector`s instead of arrays.

Comment: can't use scanf as I not not taking input from user. Plus I am working on ARM architecture so have some limitations and can't use vector :)

Comment: It's `Sscanf`, "string scanf" to read from a string buffer, so it won't read from `stdin`. Just copy four `chars` into a new buffer, add a `'\0'` after them to make it a valid string, and then try reading the string like a number and store it in the new array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strncpy` to copy 4 characters only in a temporary character array, then convert it to integer by `atoi`.

```
char tmp[5];
tmp[4] = '\0';
for (int i=0; i<250; i++)
  {
    strncpy (tmp, &char_array[i*4], 4);
    int_array[i] = atoi (tmp);
  }
```

Comment: This invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: It still invokes UB. `atoi` reads from a C-Style string, a char array terminated by a `'\0'`. Since your array is 4 byte long and you copy 4 byte into it, there is no guarantee that the string is terminated correctly and atoi will literaly scan through the whole memory until it finds a `'\0'`.

Comment: @muXXmit2X You are right. Edited.

Answer (score -3):

If all of your char components are continuous in the array , then it is simple simply cast the first adress to an int * like so :

```
char_array[0] = '0'
char_array[1] = '9'
char_array[2] = '2'
char_array[3] = '8'

int * char_array_to_int = (int *)char_array;
```

then *char_array_to_int contains the value you want.

Otherwise , you can use bit shifting to populate the int with the 4 bytes you want.

EDIT

Sorry i missed the quotes on the char array.

Then yes you need to change from the ascii representation of the number to the number itself as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Your answer don't work, you can't convert char to number like that. And the result depend of your endianness

Comment: That invokes undefined behaviour anyway.